# How to condense this function?

Tags: python

```
def average(tup):
  """ ugiufh """
   total = ((int(tup[0]) + int(tup[1]) + int(tup[2]))/3,
            (int(tup[0]) + int(tup[1]) + int(tup[2]))/3,
            (int(tup[0]) + int(tup[1]) + int(tup[2]))/3)
   return total
```

I am writing a function to average out three element in a tuple which means if the original tuple = (1, 2, 3) which give me tuple = (2, 2, 2)

My question is there any way to condense what wrote to give me the same answer? If yes, how to condense it?

Thanks

Comment: Remove `""" ugiufh """` - one line smaller. :)

Comment: Are you sure that you want to be doing integer division here? Just a question.

Comment: Don't remove it but describe the function in the docstring

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure you want integer division, you can use

```
def average(tup):
    n = len(tup)
    return (sum(int(x) for x in tup) / n,) * n
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not go all the way and make it `return (sum(int(x) for x in tup) / len(tup))*n`?

Comment: @James: Because your code (a) does not define `n` and (b) does not return a tuple.

Comment: I don't see why you can't just take `return (sum(tup) / len(tup),) * len(tup)` as in my answer... Why the generator?

Comment: @Benjamin: Because I want to reproduce the behaviour of the OP's function.  Your function does something else, which might even be what the OP wants, but is not what she asked for.

Comment: @Sven: I don't see how my solution is different than what is accomplished by the OP's code, or by yours?

Comment: @Benjamin: It does not convert the tuple items to `int` before summing them up.  Try passing in `("1", "2", "3")` or `(1.0, 2.0, 4.0)` to the two versions and look at the different results.  The second example also illustrates why I say that your version might be what the OP wants.

Comment: Who says it's integer division, maybe it's Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to condense the code you listed, but what you should really strive for is making the code more readable.

```
def average(a):
    """Return a tuple where every element of ``a`` is replaced by the average of the values of ``a``."""
    length = len(a)
    average = sum(a) / length
    return (average,) * length # A 1-tuple containing the average, repeated length times
```

This has the added benefit of being able to accept tuples of any input length.

One change that was made in this version of the code is that the elements of the tuple are not first coerced to integers. Unless there is some specialised reason why you need this, you should probably separate that logic out into a separate bit of code.

```
data = (1, '2', 3.0)
normalised_data = (int(x) for x in data) # A generator expression that yields integer-coerced elements of data
result = average(normalised_data)
```

Of course, if you insist on a condensed answer, [Sven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263287/how-to-condense-this-function/5263325#5263325) is functionally equivalent to mine.

Comment: In Python 2.x, this version will use integer division if the tuple passed in only consists of integers, but as soon as one float is included, it will compute the real average.  The OP's version (and mine) always uses integer division.  The probably most sane version probably would be to always use floating point division.

Answer (score 0):

```
def average(tup):
    def mean(t):
        return sum(t, .0) / len(t)
    return (mean(tup),) * len(tup)
```

One line:

```
def average(tup): return ((lambda t: sum(t, .0) / len(t))(tup),) * len(tup)
```

or

```
average = lambda tup: ((lambda t: sum(t, .0) / len(t))(tup),) * len(tup)
```

But the first piece of code is better than these.

Answer (score 0):

```
def average(tup):
    return (sum(tup) / len(tup),) * len(tup)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def average(tup):
    """ ugiufh """
    el = sum( map(int,tup) )/3
    return (el,el,el)
```